# How does python find the end of string?

Tags: python, string, eof

I know python has inbuilt string support. But what I would like to know is how it handles the end of string construct. C has '\0' character to signify end of string. How does python do it? It would be great if someone could tell me how it works in the cpython source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, CPython keeps track of the length and start of the string. As of CPython 3.3 it also keeps track of how many bytes per character in order to compress strings that can fit into subsets of the Unicode spectrum, such as Latin-1 strings.

Comment: The latter only exists since Python 3.3 (not 3.0 - 3.2) and is an implementation detail that doesn't have to concern you if you're not writing C code and not reasoning about the space consumption of Python code. (What's not an implementation detail is that strings now support all code points on *all* platforms.)

Comment: Good catch. The whole question asked about an implementation detail so I thought it relevant.

Comment: FYI, the length of the string is stored in a struct member of `C` type `ssize_t` (the signed variant of type `size_t`).  So the maximum length of a string may vary across platforms.  It's unlikely you'll hit the maximum before running out of memory ;-)